# definite integral with recurence

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The following is taken from Cohen-Tannoudji book: "Quantum Mechanics" Vol. 1 page 679:

[image]

I don't understand how he does this integration by parts.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $f=u$, $df=du$, and $dg=u(1-u^2)^{l-1}du$, $g=\int u(1-u^2)^{l-1}du=-\frac1{2l}(1-u^2)^l$. Then the integral equals
$$fg\big]_{-1}^1-\int_{-1}^1 g df=
-\frac1{2l}u(1-u^2)^{l}\big]_{-1}^1+\frac1{2l}\int_{-1}^1(1-u^2)^ldu
=\frac1{2l}\int_{-1}^1(1-u^2)^ldu.$$